# Appropriate statistical test with pre\post experiment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, anova

This might be very simple so excuse me in advance. I'm trying to test if the difference between five test scores is statistically significant in a pre\post experiment with three different times, as shown in the table below (where each cell have one point), what statistical test is adequate here?

---

|  | test1 | test2 | ... | test5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pre exp. |  |  |  |  |
| post exp. (time 1) |  |  |  |  |
| post exp. (time 2) |  |  |  |  |
| post exp. (time 3) |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Were subjects randomly assigned to test groups?

Comment: @DemetriPananos not sure what "randomly" means here! It was a specific material (pre) which treated with one treatment (post) but with three different periods of time (like: 5 min , 10 min, 15 min). each of the pre and post treatment tested with five chemicals tests. I hope this clarify my question.

Comment: Who are the subjects of this experiment?

Comment: @DemetriPananos I don't have subjects, just one material (pre\post) with five tests! I want to find the statistical difference between the tests results. sorry I'm not used to statistical terms so I'm little confused :)

Comment: So you only have one piece of material measured $5\times4=20$ times?

Comment: @mdewey Yes, exactly.

Comment: @mdewey Can I perform any type of statistical test to see if the result of the 5 tests different or not between pre and post exp.?

Comment: Different in what way? Different profile over time? Different average level? Without repetition this is all going to be very hard and you might just as well plot the scores against time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not answered reasonable questions in the comments and seems to have disappeared from this site.